# Method performs differently in iis and iis express

Tags: javascript, arcgis, iis-express

dojo.requiry ('esri.toolbars.draw ');
dojo.addonload(init);
 i use like  this  method to load the map. it  can  work in  iis ,but not in  iis  express.
 init method doesn't execute in  iis  express . (i use arcgis 3.16)

Comment: If you have the choice I would recommend not using dojo. It's very outdated and I found it has many bugs

Comment: You mean the problem probably came from dojo?

Comment: Not going to lie, I have no idea... but it is possible